# Error disallowed user agent Ionic 2 [InAppBrowser]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I Have a problem when loading the web page with the InAppBrowser cordova plugin. See below :

```
Error disallowed user agent
```

Code for opening page :

```
let browserRef = new InAppBrowser('http://*****:3000/auth/google/callback', '_blank');
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it works in Ionic but I fixed it in Cordova thanks to this comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/unable-to-sign-in-to-google-account-using-in-app-browsers-or-web-views-with-keycloak/89782/3

You can add `<preference name="OverrideUserAgent" value="Mozilla/5.0 Google" />` to the config.xml and the error should be gone.